# Pdf file appears smaller after inserting in ms word 2007. Why?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, microsoft-word-2007

I converted my ms word file in ms word 2007 to pdf.

When the converted pdf file is opened in Adobe reader or any pdf reader, the pdf file appears exactly the same as the ms word file in word 2007.

Now, the same pdf file is inserted into ms word through insert object, create new file.............

Yes, the pdf file is listed with all its contents successfully. No issues till now.

Now, my issue is that the font size is becoming smaller. As I resize object through the adjusting handle tool, the font size become bigger and thereby all its contents become blurry.

However, in Adobe reader, it's showing perfect but in ms word, why it's showing smaller font.

How to retain the original font size and look same as the one in pdf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be fonts that cannot be nested into pdf at the time of conversion, and pdf is automatically replaced by similar fonts.

In addition, the font library and some formatting commands they use are not uniform.

We usually have to choose to reformat and font size after conversion.

Comment: Font was times new Roman and 12 size. All regular fonts.

Comment: No matter what font you use, it may change after you convert the PDF. We usually have to choose to reformat and font size after conversion.

Comment: How to reformat and font size after conversation again??

Comment: Manually reset it as you did before...